# Any good sites for collaborating on small projects? ie animations, short films etc?

Tags: collaboration, recommendations, websites, showreel, projects

Hi all!

I'm looking to collaborate on some projects so that I can update my showreel with a few more recent works. Does anyone know of any sites where it might be useful to post some sound design/editing requests? I enjoy animation and computer visual effects stuff, as well as film. Would be interesting to hear anyone's suggestions as to where the best places are to offer services. Of course it'd be great to get paid for them, but at the moment I'd be happy to do some free collaborating for the right projects.

I live in the Southwest of England(Bournemouth) at present!

Cheers,
A.L.

Answer (score 4):

www.mandy.com can be a useful resource. Here is a direct link to the [UK job page](http://www.mandy.com/1/jobs2.cfm?t=ukew). The website is for all aspects of the film and television industry and a lot of jobs are advertised so you may have to search through a number of pages before you find any sound design offers, but it's well worth checking regularly as they do often pop up. Most sound design offers are either unpaid or low / profit share but I have worked on some interesting projects, all of which led to further job opportunities after completion. Another useful site is [Talent Circle](http://www.talentcircle.org/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Colin! Just signed up to Talent Circle and got in touch with someone looking for a sound designer, so fingers crossed!

Answer (score 2):

The [Craigslist Film/TV job board](http://london.craigslist.co.uk/tfr/) is a good resource for finding first-time or student filmmakers looking for sound designers. I'm sure that 95 out of 100 projects are pretty crappy and not worth doing, but the other 5? Well, you never know who the next Spielberg will be…

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Been a while since I used that. Seems to be mostly people looking for xxx models but I think I'll take up Matt's RSS advice and hope for better luck :)

Answer (score 2):

[Guru.com](http://www.guru.com/) sometimes has audio related stuff come up, but it's rare (and super lo-budg when it does come up).

That said, I won a bid and gained a pretty awesome client (and project) in the process. Worth a shot to throw your name in the mix at least...

Comment: Cheers Joel! I'll register and check it out in more detail later

Answer (score 2):

+1 on Craigslist. I subscribe to an RSS from their gigs page for results with "sound design". I see a couple of postings each day here in Burbank. 99% contain some variation of "We already spent our budget on stuff we thought was more important than audio, so you won't be getting paid."

Another place is Mandy.com in their jobs tab. They have a post-production option in the search. I haven't seen many results for my area, but maybe you'll have better results across the pond.

I wish I knew of more reliable sources for paying projects. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the RSS tip, Matt. I'll give it go. Don't mind collaborating with anyone across the world so will try other countries Craiglist sites too:) 

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think if this before, but there are sites like http://www.searchtempest.com/ or http://www.crazedlist.org/ that let you search Craigslist in multiple locations at once. They're kinda' slow with loading and browsing, but it's faster than searching Craigslist by each area one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of schools out there have students who are also looking to build a demo reel.  You could start posting on school forums, contacting placement departments, etc...

Most students get very excited about outside projects, no matter how small, and I'm sure most, if not all students are willing to work for free as well.  Often times you can find some very gifted students out there.  You would be building your demo reel, and helping to build theirs as well.